# Android Inflate Exception occurred

Tags: android, memory

What I have to do for this memory problem ?

```
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firewards/com.firewards.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at com.firewards.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:66)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     ... 11 more
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     ... 27 more
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
02-11 15:40:30.959: E/AndroidRuntime(5108):     ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it feels like a memory issues, try releasing some bitmaps prior to accessing that
particular View.

I suggest to check out this video http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/ which talks about Android memory management.

One thing worth mentioning is that prior to honeycomb, bitmaps were allocated in the native
heap, so watch out for it when profiling memory.
If you're on a device which if Honeycomb or newer, the bitmaps are allocated in the managed
heap.